# Problem with partially UV-unwrapping a simple object

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

Blender 2.8/Eevee,

As I've proven to myself time and time again, my texturing knowledge and skills are  abysmal...

I want to texture a part of my object with a custom texture but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried reading and watching tutorials but I believe I'm doing exactly what the tutorials say and still nothing.

Im trying to put a custom texture ONLY on the top of the counter (as indicated by the names of the material slot and UV map), I've unwrapped only that portion and used nodes to create what should have been a working material (the rest of the object is divided into other materials, by the assign button). However, nothing but the default color can be seen in rendered view. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you **assign** the materials to the faces? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Yes, each part of the object is assigned a different material.

Comment: You appear to have Use Nodes turned off for that material, and have then defined a node tree for it.  Does turning it on make any difference?

Comment: @Ben
Turning it on/off does nothing. It's a problem with the inital 3 node setup. It has to be done by Blender (by using the properties menu) or it just won't show up - just white.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

Apparrently in 2.8 you can't just add image texture nodes and link everything up like I used to do in older Blender versions. Blender will only read a texture if it's imported through the properties panel, next to the color picker button. Thought I'd try to do the exact same steps that are shown in the tutorial (even though they result in exactly the same node structure) and it worked, but trying to build an identical node setup somehow fails...

Comment: This is not the case in my version of 2.8, I can just add an image texture node and link everything up and it works.  I'd use the UV socket of the Texture Coordinates node rather than the UV Map node though, especially for a simple object.  The UV Map one is to select from different UV maps I think.

It's not clear from your question whether you've assigned any faces to slot 2 since the materials are all roughly the same colour, but if that isn't the problem I'm not sure what is.

Comment: I've been able to replicate the issue consistently. Whether I apply that UV Map node or not seems to be irrelevant (it's unnecessary and I only did it to check if it changes anything). The result is always the same - creating an image texture node manually (in the node editor) does nothing, it's all white. The texture will only show up on the object if I let Blender create the 3 basic nodes using the properties menu - I can also edit those nodes after that without any issues. The problem is only with the initial setup.